# Nativescript Vue app crashes on startup after upgrading to 7

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

A functioning Nativescript app previously using tns-core-modules@6.1.1 is failing when run on an Android emulator after upgrading Nativescript CLI v7.2.0 and @nativescript/core 7.0.13.

The only upgrade & migration information I could find are:

- https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions
- https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-import-reference/
- https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/

The upgrade instructions page seems to be specific to v6 so running ns migrate may not have been the correct first step. The NS 7 announcement post still says to use it, though.

The process I completed was to upgrade Nativescript CLI, run ns migrate, ns clean, re-add the Android platform (v7.0.1), and then update imports from tns-core-modules to @nativescript/core where they threw errors on webpack build. Also had to fix previous logic where it imported the `screen` variable from tns-core-modules/platform, and that now requires `Screen`.

After clearing those errors while running ns build android, webpack is now building the app, and installing on the emulated device. Installation takes longer than before, but it eventually reaches a point where the app splash screen appears. After maybe 1 second the splash screen disappears as the app closes. There is no information in the console output, and the console just shows "Successfully installed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'."

Are there any additional tools I can use to debug this issue?

Comment: I was able to see useful information using adb's logcat. The issue was that nativescript-sentry required and update and the DSN to be placed in AndroidManifest.  Now, when starting the app, it crashes with an error appearing on the device:

An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.XYZ.app/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaveCb' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

To see the necessary information I needed to use adb logcat. That clarified that nativescript-sentry required an update and configuration change to work with nativescript 7.